# Better implementation of switch and if comparison

Tags: java, struts2

I have this struts2 interceptor class that checks the `access` session key and decides whether to let the user proceed to seeing the actual page or display the error message page.

What is the best approach to this kind of value checking?

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invoke) throws Exception {
    Map<String,Object> session = invoke.getInvocationContext().getSession();

    Set<String> access = (Set<String>) session.get("access");
    String action = invoke.getAction().getClass().getSimpleName();

    switch(action) {
        case "ParametersHomeAction":
        case "ErrorMapAction" :
        case "FillerMusicAndLoginAction":
        case "ScheduledAction":
        case "SysConfigAction":
        case "SysParamAction":
            if(access.contains("PAR-FM") ||
               access.contains("PAR-SCHA") ||
               access.contains("PAR-EM") ||
               access.contains("PAR-SYSCNF") ||
               access.contains("PAR-CSAT")) {
                return invoke.invoke();
            } else return RESTRICTED_ERROR;

        case "ProfilesHomeAction":
        case "GroupAction":
        case "UserAction":
            if(access.contains("PFA-U") ||
               access.contains("PFA-G")) {
                return invoke.invoke();
            } else return RESTRICTED_ERROR;

        case "SystemHomeAction":
        case "FunctionAction":
        case "LockUnlockAction":
        case "WfCategoryAction":
        case "WfStatusAction":
            if(access.contains("SYSA-WC") ||
               access.contains("SYSA-WS") ||
               access.contains("SYSA-WT") ||
               access.contains("SYSA-WTU") ||
               access.contains("SYSA-LUU") ||
               access.contains("SYSA-BF")) {
                return invoke.invoke();
            } else return RESTRICTED_ERROR;

        case "ReportsHomeAction":
            if(access.contains("RP-BOAL") ||
               access.contains("RP-PBAL") ||
               access.contains("RP-PBF") ||
               access.contains("RP-PBMT") ||
               access.contains("RP-IVRMU") ||
               access.contains("RP-ACAR") ||
               access.contains("RP-AUR")) {
                return invoke.invoke();
            } else return RESTRICTED_ERROR;

        // TRANSACTIONS TO FOLLOW
        case "HomeAction": invoke.invoke();
        default: return RESTRICTED_ERROR;   
    }
}
```

Comment: Better is to use some security framework (e.g. spring-security).

Comment: If it is just about code style, implement it with a enum. This way you allign your case (=enum constant) with your `access` thingy.

Comment: You are not thinking fourth dimensionally: use "if instanceOf"  instead of "switch.. case: Class name"... at least you won't have to edit your Interceptor code every time you add an Action. Then... do like suggested by @AleksandrM :)

Comment: If you really want to do it by yourself. Then create annotation which you will use on your action classes and check it inside interceptor.

Comment: @AndreaLigios Like `if(action instanceOf ?????)`? I don't know what to put here.

Comment: Give your Actions different Interfaces (basing on your classification , like PAR, SYSA, RP and so on). Then check with instanceof which is the type.

Comment: It is probably not the best option, but is better than what you have, and it will prevent you editing your Interceptor for each newly created action

Comment: I do it by separating different actions in different packages

Answer (score 0):

You can put values in an array or list (or multiple arrays/lists) and check if a value is inside it.
For a list:

```
boolean contains(Object o)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a `Map` of classes to the permissions they require as a constant, populating it with an initializer block:

```
private static final Map<Class<?>, Set<String>> PERMISSIONS = new HashMap<Class<?>, Set<String>>() {{
    Set<String> permissions = new HashSet<String> (Arrays.asList("PAR-FM", "PAR-SCHA", "PAR-EM", "PAR-SYSCNF", "PAR-CSAT"));
    put(ParametersHomeAction.class, permissions);
    put(ErrorMapAction.class, permissions);
    put(FillerMusicAndLoginAction.class, permissions);
    put(ScheduledAction.class, permissions);
    put(SysConfigAction.class, permissions);
    put(ErrorMapAction.class, permissions);
    put(SysParamAction.class, permissions);
    permissions = new HashSet<String> (Arrays.asList("PFA-U", "PFA-G"));
    put(ProfilesHomeAction.class, permissions);
    put(GroupAction.class, permissions);
    put(UserAction.class, permissions);
    permissions = new HashSet<String> (Arrays.asList("SYSA-WC", "SYSA-WS", "SYSA-WT", "SYSA-WTU", "SYSA-LUU", "SYSA-BF"));
    put(SystemHomeAction.class, permissions);
    put(FunctionAction.class, permissions);
    put(LockUnlockAction.class, permissions);
    put(WfCategoryAction.class, permissions);
    put(WfStatusAction.class, permissions);
    permissions = new HashSet<String> (Arrays.asList("RP-BOAL", "RP-PBAL", "RP-PBF", "RP-PBMT", "RP-IVRMU", "RP-ACAR", "RP-AUR"));
    put(ReportsHomeAction.class, permissions);
    permissions = new HashSet<String>(); // special case for no permission required
    put(HomeAction.class, permissions);
}};
```

Then by looking this map up, your method can become simply:

```
public String intercept(ActionInvocation invoke) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> session = invoke.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    Set<String> access = (Set<String>) session.get("access");
    Set<String> permissionSet = PERMISSIONS.get(invoke.getAction().getClass());
    if (permissionSet == null || (!permissionSet.isEmpty() && !access.removeAll(permissionSet)))
        return RESTRICTED_ERROR;
    return invoke.invoke();
}
```

This code will produce equivalent results to your code. The "power" is contained in the `if`:

- `permissionSet == null` mimics your `switch default`
- `!permissionSet.isEmpty()` handles your special case of there being no requirements for `HomeAction`
- `Set.removeAll()` returns `true` if the set was changed by removing all of the elements of the set passed to it, so `!access.removeAll(permissionSet)` is `true` if `access` contained *none* of the elements in `permissionSet`